# Rails association within a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have two models that are not directly associated with one another `Client` and `PotentialClient` and I want to be able to create a `join` between them.

Both models have the field `mindbody_id` but it is **only** unique within a `Location`.  Both `Client` and `PotentialClient` belong to a `Location`.

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :location
end

class PotentialClient < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :location
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :potential_clients
    has_many :clients
end
```

**How can I join on mindbody_id given that it is present in both `Client` an `PotentialClient` and unique within a `Location`?**

I thought something like this would work but it did not:

```
#client.rb
has_one :potential_client, -> {
    where(potential_clients: {location_id: self.location_id, mindbody_id: self.mindbody_id})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work

```
has_one :potential_client, -> { where(mindbody_id: mindbody_id }, through: :location
```

This should get all the "potential_clients" from the location, then apply the scope and you should have only one PotentialClient

Comment: It's throwing an error because location `has_many :potential_clients`:

ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) "potential_client" or :potential_client in model Location. Try 'has_many :potential_client, :through => :location, :source => <name>'. Is it one of reviews, potential_clients, users, employees, clients, check_ins, weigh_ins, weekly_reports, consult_stats, or mind_body_sales?

Comment: I guess it's `has_one ....., through: :location, source: :potential_clients`